# Specifying type of exception that a function can throw

Tags: c++, exception

I've been trying to learn Exception Handling in CPP and following one of the video tutorials, I came across this:

```
/*
Write a simple program to illustrate exception specification, which means putting a constraint on the type of exception that a function can throw.
*/
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void divide(int x,int y) throw(int,double){
    try{
        if (x==25 && y==0) throw x;
        if (x==34 && y==0) throw 90.7;
        if (x==98 && y==0) throw "error encountered";
    }
    catch(int x){
        cout << x << endl;
    }
    catch (float y){
        cout << y<<endl;
    }
    catch (const char *d){
        cout << d << endl;
    }
}
int main(){
    divide (25,0);
    divide (34,0);
    divide(98,0);
    return 0;
}
```

On compiling, in VS Code, it gives the following warning:

```
 Q6.cpp:6:26: warning: dynamic exception specifications are deprecated in C++11 [-Wdeprecated]
    6 | void divide(int x,int y) throw(int,double){
  |                          ^~~~~
```

Can someone explain what's wrong with my code?

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec

Comment: Exception specifications were a bad idea. They’ve gone away. Your tutorial is out of date.